# Add to cart redirect

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, url, redirect, addtocart

How can redirect to a CMS page when the "add to cart button" (on a product view page) is clicked?

I have already disabled the redirect to the cart page after the "add to cart" button is clicked. Now I need to know what code edits to make to direct the browser to a new page.

Answer (score 3):

Edit template for product view page `YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

Replace this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
```

With this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product, array('return_url' => 'YOUR CMS PAGE URL')) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
```

Comment: How to redirect to previous page??

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest listening to the event `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`. Here you can use the following code to set a `return_url` in an observer.

```
$observer->getRequest()->setParam('return_url', Mage::Helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl($page_id));
```

Comment: @Seabstien: It doesn't work for me.

I have an error and report file contains :

a:5:{i:0;s:41:"External urls redirect to "http:" denied!";i:1;s:1163:"#0

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

i am facing issue when i add item to cart its redirect to cart page,

i have change the redirect to NO from admin but now its direct open checkout page
i need it like this when i click the add to cart button it should added to mincart but not leave the product page, after adding when i click the cart from there i can use open cart button to open the cart page.
thanks